# Data connection Check in Windows Phone 8 Development

Tags: windows-phone-8

We use WCF Service for fetching data's to controls. Do we need to check the Network connection availability ?

Note: We haven't found any application certification related points for checking network availability. If not check any certification failure ?

Answer (score 3):

you can check if there is a connection available (first function) or type of aconnection (second function)

```
public static bool checkConnection()
    {
        return Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
    }

    public static int typeConnection()
    {
        switch (Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType)
        {
            default:
                return 0;
            case Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceType.MobileBroadbandCdma:
                return 1;
            case Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceType.MobileBroadbandGsm:
                return 1;
            case Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceType.None:
                return 2;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use:

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation;
public bool isNetworkConnected()
{
  return DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable;
}
```

Works like a charm.